# How to make a macro universally usable on multiple workstations with different usernames

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro that I built for a specific work related task.  I share this macro with a few people by sending them the .xlam file as an addin.  No problems there.

My problem is that some of the code I use has my personal username embedded within it, so when I share the xlam, I have to save a separate xlam file for each person I share the macro with, and edit the username in each one to match the person I am sending it to.  For example:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Agent List for DSR.xlsx"
```

I have to change "myusername" so that it works for my colleagues when they are running the macro on their work station.

is there another syntax I can use that basically says...  current user...  and will work universally for all who open it on their workstation?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim xlsPath As String
xlsPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Agent List for DSR.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open xlsPath
```

Comment: Well, it opens on my workstation using your code, so I have some confidence that it will work when I distribute the next version of this macro to the rest of my team.  Thanks!